# C code compiled with an online C compiler wont run on visual studio anymore

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
//Program that calculates values from two entered integers
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int sum, diff, prod, quo, rem;

    printf("Enter first integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &i1);
    printf("Enter second integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &i2);

    sum = i1 + i2;
    diff = i1 - i2;
    prod = i1 * i2;
    quo = i1 / i2;
    rem = i1 % i2;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Sum of %d and %d is: %d \n", i1, i2, sum);
    printf("Diffrence between %d and %d is: %d \n",i1,i2,diff);
    printf("Product of %d and %d is: %d \n", i1, i2, prod);
    printf("Quotient of %d and %d is: %d \n", i1, i2, quo);
    printf("Remainder of %d and %d is: %d \n", i1, i2, rem);
    printf("\n");
    printf("MIND BLOWN?");

}
```

This is just a simple C code that I wrote in visual studio and I compiled it online with a C compiler and then downloaded the file, but now after reopening the file in visual studio it wont build or run. How do I fix this? The usual panes are gone. I have to submit this as an assignment, will this be an issue on my professors computer as well?

[image]

Comment: Probably you have to create a VS project.

Comment: Light, Code as text uses `scanf()`.  Code as picture uses `scanf_s()`.  What is the true code?  Why doe these differ?

Comment: What exactly does "won't build or run" mean?  What happens when you try to compile?  What errors/warnings if any do you get?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+L.

Comment: There are no errors or warnings, when i try to build or run the prgrm it just stays the same

Comment: So I can only create a project and run the file?

Comment: If you want to compile and run something using Visual Studio, you need to create a project and make that something a part of the project.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That is probably the answer to the question, actually. I wouldn't close this question as this seems like a common enough problem that others might encounter - many IDE do support executing a single .c file outside of creating a project.